# How can i fill an array from another one in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays :

The first one has combinations of fruits:

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Pineaple] => 4
            [Strawberry] => 1
        )

    [Watermelon] => Array
        (
            [Peach] => 3
        )

)
```

The second is this, it is empty because I want to storage from the first one:

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Pineaple] => 0
            [Strawberry] => 0
            [Watermelon] => 0
            [Peach] => 0
        )

    [Watermelon] => Array
        (
            [Pineaple] => 0
            [Strawberry] => 0
            [Watermelon] => 0
            [Peach] => 0
        )
)
```

I want to pass the information to the second array like this. It must have all the combinations of fruits and the number of incidences.

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Pineaple] => 4
            [Strawberry] => 1
            [Watermelon] => 0
            [Peach] => 0
        )

    [Watermelon] => Array
        (
            [Pineaple] => 0
            [Strawberry] => 0
            [Watermelon] => 0
            [Peach] => 3
        )
)
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet, if so show it to us

Comment: Read this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php  and the first comment there is what you are looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#92195

Comment: Implementation of advice from dupe target: https://3v4l.org/KfRhT

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a foreach loop nightmare but this works

It walks through the first array and checks if the relevant keys exist in the second array, if they do it adds the value from array 1 to array 2.

It will not create new occurances in the second array, but if thats what you want to do it would be simple to change.

```
$one = [
        ['Apple' => ['Pineaple' => 4, 'Strawberry'=>1]],
        ['Watermelon' => ['Peach' => 3]]
];
#print_r($one);
$two = [
        'Apple' => ['Pineaple' => 0, 'Strawberry' => 0, 'Watermelon' => 0, 'Peach' => 0],
        'Watermelon' => ['Pineaple' => 0, 'Strawberry' => 0, 'Watermelon' => 0, 'Peach' => 0]
];
#print_r($two);

foreach($one as $o) {
    foreach($o as $key => $row) {
        // check we have a key in array 2
        if ( isset( $two[$key]) ) {
            foreach( $row as $fruit => $val ){
                // check we have that key in the sub array
                if ( isset( $two[$key][$fruit]) ) {
                    $two[$key][$fruit] = $two[$key][$fruit] + $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($two);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Pineaple] => 4
            [Strawberry] => 1
            [Watermelon] => 0
            [Peach] => 0
        )

    [Watermelon] => Array
        (
            [Pineaple] => 0
            [Strawberry] => 0
            [Watermelon] => 0
            [Peach] => 3
        )
)
```

Comment: I don't find this answer to be very inspiring or representative of the quality of your programming ability.

Comment: Ah, you've over-delivered.  The OP isn't explicitly asking for summing but that is what you've built.  I interpret the question as needing to lay a set of values overtop a default array.